# How to check if submitbutton detect click

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

Hello Please I try learn this tutorial

[Yii2 tutorial 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOcmETyZsgA)

But not working, when I click on submit button not change... if edit it's empty or not...

I thing so `<?= Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>`  not detect click, how can check it?

here are my code

in siteControler

```
public function actionUser()
    {
        $model = new UserForm;

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'You have entered the data correctly');
        }
        return $this->render('userForm',['model'=>$model]);
    }
```

models UserForm.php

```
 <?php
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class UserForm extends Model{
    public $name;
    public $email;


    public function rules(){
        return [
                    [['name','email'],'required'],
                    ['email','email']
                  ];
    }
}
```

site userForm.php

```
   <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

?>

<?php
    if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')){
        echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success');
    }
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'name') ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'email') ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>
```

I control from video but I thing so it's 1:1 on video work good but for me, no.. why?

Thanks

---

**my code.. I put into name : adfs  and into email: asd@gmail.com and press Submit button, and I want shown on top 'You have entered the data correctly' but not shown... I thing so I can't detect when press button**

Comment: It means $model is not validated btw your created form has fields or not?

Comment: yes model is not validatet.

Comment: your code has no fields like textInput, dropdownList. so how are you getting values?

Comment: I am amateur in this I try follow tutorial (link upper) please you can direct me on page when I can learn work with formulars? or some tutorial? because I only described code from video. (maybe I have a mistake but I don't know where. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it you have not closed $form obj, that why you're submit was not triggering.
Try this view code site userForm.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

?>

<?php
if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')){
    echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success');
}
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'name')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'email')->textInput() ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Let me know if it not working.

Comment: yes work, thanks... please can you give me a theory? when Use $form = ActiveForm::begin(); I must use  ActiveForm::end(); too? 

or?

Comment: Yes, it is must. just like <form> starts and it must be closed with </form>, so $form=ActiveForm::begin i.e <form> and ActiveForm::end() i.e </form>